# sympy - how to remove all constants from an expression?

Tags: python, sympy

so I've got this kind of sympy expression: `1**3 + 1**2 + 1*x**2 + 2*1*x + 1 + 2*x + 2` and I want it to be like `1*x**2 + 2*1*x + 2*x`. how can I achieve this without going all the way down through the expression's args? 
thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. The expression you show would automatically simplify in sympy.

Comment: If you have `expr = 1**3 + 1**2 + 1*x**2 + 2*1*x + 1 + 2*x + 2` then `expr - expr.subs(x, 0)` would be the expression without the constant term. It would be helpful if you explain how you create and want to use these expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods that can be used to slice-n-dice expressions. Since you want to get rid of all non-x terms (from the sound of it) you can use `as_independent`.

Create your equation similar to how you presented it:

```
>>> eq= S('1**3 + 1**2 + 1*x**2 + 2*1*x + 1 + 2*x + 2', evaluate=False)
>>> eq
x**2 + 2*x + 2*x + 1**3 + 1**2 + 1 + 2
```

Now get the x-independent and x-dependent parts:

```
>>> eq.as_independent(x)
(5, x**2 + 2*x + 2*x)
>>> _[1]
x**2 + 2*x + 2*x
```

If it is important to have the terms not evaluate you can get close to that with

```
>>> from sympy import UnevaluatedExpr as Hold
>>> o=Hold(1)
>>> t=Hold(2)
>>> o**3 + o**2 + o*x**2 + t*o*x + o + t*x + t
x**2*1 + x*2 + x*2*1 + 1 + 1**2 + 1**3 + 2
>>> _.as_independent(x)
(1 + 1**2 + 1**3 + 2, x**2*1 + x*2 + x*2*1)
```